# Sports Player Ratings Algorithm

Tags: statistics

Ok so I went to ask this in the sports section and my question was deleted. So I am guessing that since no one said anything and my question got deleted, this is a math question and that's why I am asking here now. **If this is not the right section, please kindly let me know**.

*Inside the Edge* is a sports stats program that ranks the player 0-100.   How does *Inside the Edge* figure out their total or complete number on the player? Does anyone have any idea on the break down? I'm trying to get an idea on how they get their total number. Any information would be helpful.

Comment: It's possible that this question could be asked here, but without any guidance from you about what goes into the program, or even a link (to what frankly seems like a commercial product?), this question runs a significant risk of getting closed fairly quickly.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, it's "their program."  Don't mean to pick on you, but bad grammar is prone to push an iffy question over the edge.

Comment: Good luck finding information on this. Copyright issues galore.

Comment: I'm not hiding anything what was bad with my grammar? Or what did I mispell? As for there math  they show what needs to be inserted. Its not so much that I have to something exactly its just a idea of the math problem itself. Also is there a better site to post this on?

Comment: Not a copyright issue *per se*, is my guess (since copyright doesn't prevent one from *knowing* the content), but intellectual property, surely.  Probably some kind of trade secret.

Comment: What @BrianTung said.

Comment: Who downvoted me and why. Please tell me what I am not understanding? Why is this getting a downvote. Im not trying to be jerk I just want to know the truth. I would love to learn.

Comment: @user318816: You (or *someone*) had written "there number" and "there program"; in both cases, it should be "their." ¶ More significantly, I think boiling player values down to single values (i.e., scalars) loses so much information about sports players in general as to be practically worthless.  All they tell you is how closely the player aligns with what the scale designer thinks is important.  (To be sure, that's not a problem with holistic scales like plus/minus, but then those metrics are exceedingly sensitive to context and small sample sizes.)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can easily guess.  This site is generally for mathematics questions where the asker has a specific problem with *known* inputs.  *If* your question had said, "There's an algorithm, and I know it only takes points, assists, rebounds, blocks, and steals as input, and outputs a number between $0$ and $100; here are a dozen players with correct outputs," there's a *chance* such a question would be received OK (it's too much to expect that it would be well-received).  You're asking folks to go *search* for a program and hunt down the info to answer the question?  Good luck.

Comment: @Brian Tung You are half right on a few things. With all the programs there is a final number but it does have more break downs, for example slow or how fast they are, which I didn't explain (Please see the picture for example - http://cdn2.sportsgamersonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Donaldson-overall.jpg) And yes you are correct I am asking for help on the hunt,  but not a program itself. And yes you are correct I could have worded it better sorry again for my english that was not my intetion. I want to know what they do, but I want to do it better, I will be building something myself.

Answer (score 0):

The total number is probably based on how good the player is at each element.

For example (football):

tackle = 20

dribble = 50

shoot = 90

Then they do (20+50+90)/3

This would then give them an average.

Comment: Thank you this is the best answer I got. So I guess it could come down to all there numbers to make one. but then that just leaves me with the final number maybe.. Or where they tackle from at what speed etc.. (But sooo much more)

Comment: Glad this helped. If this is the answer you were looking for please mark it as the answer (Pressing the tick next to my post)

Comment: Its not the answer I was looking for in general, However it is the best. I was just really looking for a better break down, a better idea, more information. Thats why I tried to put it in the sports section. In other words what are they keeping track of that there software program that they are selling that they do not give to to public or what is the middle equation. Or if I have half the equation what would be the easiest way of figuring out.